# How to trigger useEffect() with multiple dependencies only on button click and on nothing else

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

function callSearchApi(userName: string, searchOptions: SearchOptions, searchQuery: string): Promise<SearchResult>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const searchResult =
            searchOptions.fooOption
            ? ["Foo 1", "Foo 2", "Foo 3"]
            : ["Bar 1", "Bar 2"]
        setTimeout(()=>resolve(searchResult), 3000)
    })
}

type SearchOptions = {
    fooOption: boolean
}

type SearchResult = string[]

export type SearchPageProps = {
    userName: string
}

export function SearchPage(props: SearchPageProps) {
    const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState<SearchResult>([])
    const [searchOptions, setSearchOptions] = useState<SearchOptions>({fooOption: false})
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>("")
    const [lastSearchButtonClickTimestamp, setLastSearchButtonClickTimestamp] = useState<number>(Date.now())
    // ####################
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsSearching(true)
        setSearchResult([])
        const doSearch = () => callSearchApi(props.userName, searchOptions, searchQuery)
        doSearch().then(newSearchResult => {
            setSearchResult(newSearchResult)
            setIsSearching(false)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            setIsSearching(false)
        })
    }, [lastSearchButtonClickTimestamp])
    // ####################
    const handleSearchButtonClick = () => {
        setLastSearchButtonClickTimestamp(Date.now())
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={searchOptions.fooOption}
                        onChange={ev => setSearchOptions({fooOption: ev.target.checked})}
                    />
                    Foo Option
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={searchQuery}
                    placeholder="Search Query"
                    onChange={ev => setSearchQuery(ev.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleSearchButtonClick} disabled={isSearching}>
                    {isSearching ? "searching..." : "Search"}
                </button>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div>
                <label>Search Result: </label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    readOnly={true}
                    value={searchResult}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchPage
```

also see [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mysearchpage-wbqon).

The code works fine. I can change the search query in the text field and click the option checkbox. Once, I am ready, I can click the "Search" button and only then the side effect occurs by fetching the data.

Now, the problem is that the compiler complains about:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'props.user.loginName', 'searchFilter', and 'searchQuery'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps]

However, if I add `props.user.loginName`, `searchFilter` and `searchQuery` to the dependency list, then the side effect is triggered whenever I click the checkbox or type a single character in the text field.

I do understand the concept of hook dependencies, but I don't know how to first enter some data and only with a button click trigger the side effect.

What is the best practice for this? I have read both https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html and https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data but couldn't find any example concerning my question.

**Update 1:**

I have also come up with [this solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/mysearchpage-solution-idea-xddgd) which looks like:

```
type DoSearch = {
    call: ()=>Promise<SearchResult>
}

export function SearchPage(props: SearchPageProps) {
    const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState<SearchResult>([])
    const [searchOptions, setSearchOptions] = useState<SearchOptions>({fooOption: false})
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>("")
    const [doSearch, setDoSearch] = useState<DoSearch>()

    // ####################
    useEffect(() => {
        if(doSearch !==undefined){
            setIsSearching(true)
            setSearchResult([])
            doSearch.call().then(newSearchResult => {
                setSearchResult(newSearchResult)
                setIsSearching(false)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                setIsSearching(false)
            })
        }
    }, [doSearch])
    // ####################
    const handleSearchButtonClick = () => {
        setDoSearch({call: () => callSearchApi(props.userName, searchOptions, searchQuery)})
    }
    return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

Now the actual function is the only dependency which works fine and the compiler is happy, too.
However, what I do not like, is that fact that I need that wrapper object with the `call` property.
If I want to pass an arrow function directly to the state, this does not work as expected, e.g.:

```
const [doSearch, setDoSearch] = useState<()=>Promise<SearchResult>>()
...
setDoSearch(() => callSearchApi(props.userName, searchOptions, searchQuery))
```

The `doSearch` is not set to the arrow function, but `callSearchApi` is executed straight away. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove `setIsSearching(true)` from your effect, and set it apart when you click your button.

```
const handleSearchButtonClick = () => {
        setLastSearchButtonClickTimestamp(Date.now())
        setIsSearching(true);
    }
```

Then, you can modify your `useEffect` statement like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!isSearching) {
           return false;
        }
        setSearchResult([])
        const doSearch = () => callSearchApi(props.userName, searchOptions, searchQuery)
        doSearch().then(newSearchResult => {
            setSearchResult(newSearchResult)
            setIsSearching(false)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            setIsSearching(false)
        })
    }, [allYourSuggestedDependencies]) // add all the suggested dependencies
```

This will accomplish what you are looking for. Another way would be just disabling the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule.

If you just need to trigger the fetch only when the button is clicked, I'd just use a function.

`useEffect` is useful for instance, when you have a list of filters (toggles), and you want to make a fetch every time you toggle one filter (imagine an e-commerce). This is a naive example, but it makes the point:

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchProducts(filters);
}, [filters])
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. I think this would work. Would you consider this best practice? Am I the only one who ran into this kind of issue?

Comment: I think it's just a weird scenario. I had a similar scenario in the past. I had filters, and you could "save" them. Every time you saved them, a fetch was made. Obviously, when you entered the page, an initial fetch was also made. I believe it's not a good practice to just disable the rule. It could lead you into bugs in the future when you add a dependency. Furthermore, you'd have to leave a comment explaining why you are disabling it. It might be confusing for everybody trying to understand that effect.

Comment: So, my question would be: do you have an initial fetch or another trigger for this effect? If not, it could be just a function.

Comment: But is this not a common, daily scenario that one has a form with several input elements and only when the user clicks some sort of confirm/submit button, the backend should be consulted?

Comment: No, I do not have an initial fetch. I just want the backend to be called, once the button is clicked. When the promise resolves, the React component should display the result.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd recommend you just using a function instead of an effect. As you have experienced, it's waaaay more overhead to implement it like this. I'll edit my answer to show an example of using an effect in a beneficial way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216729/discussion-between-federico-alecci-and-joerg).

Comment: Thanks. I also updated my question with another solution, I found, but has different issues.

Comment: Thank you buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

That is how useEffect supposed to be.

- `props.userName` make sense to be in the dependency list, cuz we definitely want to fetch new data when userName is changed.
- `searchOptions` and `searchQuery` when you have this case, it's better to use reducer, so you just need to dispatch action ==> `searchOptions` and `searchQuery` won't be inside `userEffect`. [This article from Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#decoupling-updates-from-actions)  provides deep explanation and they simple example implementing it

I quickly convert your example using `useReducer`, please have a look

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

function callSearchApi(
  userName: string,
  searchOptions: SearchOptions,
  searchQuery: string
): Promise<SearchResult> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const searchResult = searchOptions.fooOption
      ? ["Foo 1", "Foo 2", "Foo 3"]
      : ["Bar 1", "Bar 2"];
    setTimeout(() => resolve(searchResult), 3000);
  });
}

const initialState = {
  searchOptions: { fooOption: false },
  searchQuery: "",
  startSearch: false, // can replace searching
  searchResult: []
};

const reducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SEARCH_START":
      return { ...state, startSearch: true, setSearchResult: [] }; //setSearchResult: [] base on your example
    case "SEARCH_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, setSearchResult: action.data, startSearch: false };
    case "SEARCH_FAIL":
      return { ...state, startSearch: false };
    case "UPDATE_SEARCH_OPTION":
      return { ...state, searchOptions: { fooOption: action.data } };
    case "UPDATE_SEARCH_QUERY":
      return { ...state, searchQuery: action.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function SearchPage(props: SearchPageProps) {
  const [
    lastSearchButtonClickTimestamp,
    setLastSearchButtonClickTimestamp
  ] = useState<number>(Date.now());
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const { searchOptions, startSearch, searchQuery, searchResult } = state;
  // ####################
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "SEARCH_START" });
  }, [lastSearchButtonClickTimestamp]);
  // ####################
  const handleSearchButtonClick = () => {
    setLastSearchButtonClickTimestamp(Date.now());
  };

  if (startSearch) {
    callSearchApi(props.userName, searchOptions, searchQuery)
      .then(newSearchResult => {
        dispatch({ type: "SEARCH_SUCCESS", data: newSearchResult });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch({ type: "SEARCH_FAIL" });
      });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={searchOptions.fooOption}
            onChange={ev =>
              dispatch({
                type: "UPDATE_SEARCH_OPTION",
                data: ev.target.checked
              })
            }
          />
          Foo Option
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={searchQuery}
          placeholder="Search Query"
          onChange={ev =>
            dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SEARCH_QUERY", data: ev.target.value })
          }
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleSearchButtonClick} disabled={startSearch}>
          {startSearch ? "searching..." : "Search"}
        </button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div>
        <label>Search Result: </label>
        <input type="text" readOnly={true} value={searchResult} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```

[Codesandbox for that](https://codesandbox.io/s/mysearchpage-yevy2)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was hoping to avoid the whole `useReducer` topic for sake of simplicity. Also, AFAIK reducers make most sense if you have a complex state machine where states depend on other states, etc. In my case it's just a "fire and forget" button click. It does not feel right to introduce reducers just for this. But I will reconsider it.

Comment: I updated my answer with `useReducer` version, Please have a look

Comment: This scenario is weird one, if you just need to call api when click button, you can call it in `handleSearchButtonClick `, if you want call it on state of `lastSearchButtonClickTimestamp `, `useReducer` is the good way to go.

Comment: Yeah, Federico Alecci mentioned that, too. Maybe I got confused, because all the examples regarding data fetching that I could find online, all use `useEffect`. Even the the official React documenation links to https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data where only `useEffect` is described. I somehow assumed that long running data fetching has to go through `useEffect` in order to not screw up the React lifecycle and/or rendering. That was a missconception I guess. Is that correct?

Comment: That's not the reason. The reason example you found is want to call the api after first (initial render) AND when ever the dependencies changed.n your case.

I don't think you want to search on initial render. 

but Yes, It's better to put it in `useEffect` to make sure that api is called only when the component is mounted in the most of cases.

Comment: Okay, but when I call the api directly in the button's onClick-handler, then the component is definitely mounted, before the api is called. Is that correct? The button can only be clicked after the whole component mounted, I guess.

Comment: Yes, Correct. I don't know what is the purpose of `lastSearchButtonClickTimestamp`, most of cases we call search api in `handleSearchButtonClick`

Comment: Thanks. I will do this, too. You and Federico Alecci both helped me a lot. Unfortunately, I can only select one answer. I will select Federico's, because it is closer to what I wanted to achieve, but that's only, because I used `useEffect` for the wrong reason. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your explanations.

Comment: That's ok. I'm glad it helped @Joerg

Answer (score 0):

With latest React you can simply use:

Define all dependencies and check for availability with a if statement:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (router.isReady && currentUser && id) {
    console.log('current user:', currentUser.uid);
    const user_role = getUserRole(id, currentUser.uid);
  }
}, [router.isReady, currentUser, id]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Side effects are not meant for that. But if you want to execute the useEffect when there is change in variable, you can put that in dependency array.

Example

```
 function effect() {
       let [n, setN] = useState('')
       useEffect(() => {
            //some api need to call when 'n' value updated everytime.
         }, [n])

        //update the N variable with ur requirement
         const updateN = (val) => {
            setN(val)
          }
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why are side effects not meant for that? AFAIK, fetching data from the backend is meant to be implemented by useEffect(), as described in https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data which is kind of the reference article on this topic.

What am I missing? Also, could you elaborate on your answer, please. How is that related to my question? I have used the techniques that you are scatching in your answer.