# How to store values of a function type (e.g. arrow functions) with the React Hook useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In Javascript and Typescript, (arrow) functions are supposed to be first class citizens. Hence, I expect that I can have function types in my React state. However, the React Hook `useState` does not seem to play nicely with function types.

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function callApi(num: number): number {
  console.log(`Api called with number ${num}. This should never happen.`);
  return num;
}

type Command = () => number;

function Foo() {
  const [command, setCommand] = useState<Command>();
  console.log(`command is ${command}.`);
  // ####################
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log("Button clicked.");
    const myCommand = () => callApi(42);
    setCommand(myCommand);
  };
  // ####################
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Change state</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Foo;
```

in [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mysearchpage-solution-idea-09fte?file=/src/Foo.tsx)

When I visit the page and click the button, I get the following console output:

```
command is undefined. 
Button clicked. 
Api called with number 42. This should never happen. 
command is 42.
```

Hence, one can see that although in my button handler the state variable `command` should be set to a new arrow function, React does not do that. Instead, it executes the new arrow function and stores the result in the state variable.

Why is that and how can I store functions in React state without having to use some inconvenient wrapper object?

For context: Quite often it would be convenient to build certain command functions by means of various user inputs and store them in state for later use, e.g. when building a job queue.

Comment: It's `undefined` because you did not pass initial value as `useState<Command>()` to your state. Also most probably in the original code `callApi` is asynchronous and `myCommand` is still `undefined` in your function once calling inside the `setCommand` one. You can use `async` and `await` keywords with `useEffect` hook for this scenario. I guess the article [How to fetch data with React Hooks?](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) would help.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that and how can I store functions in React state without having to use some inconvenient wrapper object?

**Why?**

React's `useState` takes in either a function (that it'll use as callback that gets the current value of the state) or a value, so if you pass `() => callApi(42)` it will understand it like you want the new State to be the return value of `callApi` when passing in a `42`.

**What can you do?**

If you really need to do that this way (storing a function in the state), you can do something like `useCommand(() => myCommand)`.

However, I would suggest you don't store functions in your component's state.

If you need a new instance of a function (or a new function) when something in your code has changed, use `useCallback` or `useMemo` instead.

Either will create a new function whenever one of the values specified in the dependencies array is changed.

`useCallback` will create a new function when their dependencies changed, so you can use it like:

```
function Button() {
  const [buttonAction, setButtonAction] = useState(null);

  // dynamicHandler will be a new function every time buttonAction changes
  const dynamicHandler = useCallback(() => {
    // Logic here based on the buttonAction value
  }, [buttonAction]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonAction(BUTTON_ACTIONS.DO_SOMETHING);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} />
  );
}
```

Check out the `useCallback` [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Comment: Ah okay. I've always considered `useCallback` as a wrapper for callback functions passed into my component by `props`. This is new to me. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thinking about it again. What would I do, if I only wanted to save a new function on button blick? The "function setup" has a few dependencies, but I only want to store the function, once the user clicks the button. Or in other words: How do I combine the button's `onClick` event with `useCallback`? This might probably be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595701/how-to-trigger-useeffect-with-multiple-dependencies-only-on-button-click-and-o/62596195

Comment: I edited my answer to give you an example of how I would do it. Just keep in mind that the dependencies array is your best ally when dealing with memoized values, whether they are a primitive value or a function.

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is that both the callback and the logic are local to the Button component now. But then again, I have not provided enough context for you. My production code feels too complex for a condensed sample code snippet. I will see if I can update my question, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can store function as object

```
setCommand({  function:()=>callApi(42)  })
```

Then when you want to call the function stored in state, you can simply do `command.function()`